# How to compare the forecast accuracy of two models when the data has unbalanced panel structure?

Tags: forecasting, unbalanced-classes, accuracy, paired-comparisons

I am comparing the earnings forecast accuracy of two models (model 1 and model 2).

The data (firm-year level data) have an unbalanced panel structure since firms have varying lifetime and time to be listed. These are the steps I did:

1. Compute the absolute error of the two models for all the observations.
2. For each year (from 1969-2008), get the mean error of the two models for all firms. This results in two variables for model 1 and model 2 respectively, each has 40 observations.
3. Compare the mean of the two variables using a simple t-test and ignore the fact that each observation of the two variables is a mean value.

One of my peers shares his concern that the way I compare the two models may not be valid, because, in step 3, I ignore the fact that each observation of the two variables is a mean value and may result in the loss of much information. However, he himself is not crystally clear. Does the step 3 problematic and how to fix?

Thanks for your help!